# Debian Installer With Backported Kernel

Tags: debian, kernel

I need to install Debian Jessie on a new machine, however I need the backported `linux-image-amd64` and `firmware-iwlwifi` packages from jessie-backports in the installer to support my hardware.

I was hoping to get some direction on how to create a `debian-installer` with backported firmware, or get the backported firmware on an existing machine (without network access). How could I go about doing that?

I have seen:

[Debian-Installer: Building images with a custom kernel](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify/CustomKernel)

[Backported d-i images archive](http://kmuto.jp/debian/d-i/) (Jessie is not included)

Comment: Isn't installing stretch an option for you? According to http://release.debian.org, *Debian 9 "stretch" will be released on June 17, 2017.* That is, stretch will become the new stable in 9 days.

Comment: Unless you are going to install Debian on lots of machines and you need this package to be available to every computer you are going to install it, I would follow @FerencWágner's advice, or install Debian Jessie and add backports mirror.

Comment: @FerencWágner That's perfect. Had no idea this would be released so soon. That will do what I need. Thanks!